# Orientable surface bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, fibre-bundles, symplectic-topology

Is it true that every orientable surface bundle can be made into a symplectic fibration?If yes, why?

What about the  particular case that  $M$ is a connected   compact 4-manifold?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a consquence of a theorem of THurston on the existence of symplectic fibrations.

See page 6 here for a proof.

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9c1a/c1ff4ccb03aab1633c1a6f97458b7054d9e4.pdf